# Optimizing a recursive postgres query that uses where clause and a lot of ANDs / ORs

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, graph, query-optimization

I want to create a graph whose nodes are choosen from a dataset (bidirectional_edges) using a recursive query. Basically the resulting table starts with a source node (choosen by the user) and joins the target node related to the first. Next, the recursive query selects the target of the last ones already selected. When a node has more than 20 relations, I don’t want to show the next nodes related to it, so I called the nodes with more than 20 relations by “censored”. There are two types of relations: one and two, and consequently, two ways the nodes could be censored.

The problem is that the way I built the code it takes so much time to load when the number of nodes and censored nodes are big. I've already tried to insert in the bidirectional_edges table the information of censored nodes by flags to eliminate the left joins with the censored tables, but the running time doesn't reduced considerably. The bidirectional_edges are indexed by the SOURCE_ID and TARGET_ID.

Is there a way to optimize the query? I think that the problem is in the where clause with several ANDs and ORs.

Here is an example of the dataset bidirectional_edges, censored_nodes_one and censored_nodes_two:

```
CREATE TABLE bidirectional_edges (
 SOURCE_ID integer NOT NULL,
 TARGET_ID integer NOT NULL,
 FLAG_ONE integer NOT NULL,
 FLAG_TWO integer NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO bidirectional_edges(SOURCE_ID, TARGET_ID, FLAG_ONE, FLAG_TWO)
VALUES
(1,2,1,0),
(1,3,0,1),
(2,5,1,1),
(2,6,0,1),
(2,7,1,0),
(2,8,1,0),
(2,9,1,0),
(2,10,1,0),
(2,11,1,0),
(2,12,1,0),
(2,13,1,0),
(2,14,1,0),
(2,15,1,0),
(2,16,1,0),
(2,17,1,0),
(2,18,1,0),
(2,19,1,0),
(2,20,1,0),
(2,21,1,0),
(2,22,1,0),
(2,23,1,0),
(2,24,1,0),
(2,25,1,0),
(2,26,1,0),
(2,27,1,0),
(2,28,1,0),
(2,29,1,0),
(2,30,1,0),
(3,4,1,1),
(3,31,0,1),
(3,32,0,1),
(3,33,0,1),
(3,34,0,1),
(3,35,0,1),
(3,36,0,1),
(3,37,0,1),
(3,38,0,1),
(3,39,0,1),
(3,40,0,1),
(3,41,0,1),
(3,42,0,1),
(3,43,0,1),
(3,44,0,1),
(3,45,0,1),
(3,46,0,1),
(3,47,0,1),
(3,48,0,1),
(3,49,0,1),
(3,50,0,1),
(3,51,0,1),
(3,52,0,1),
(3,53,0,1),
(3,54,0,1),
(3,55,0,1)
;


CREATE TABLE censored_nodes_one (
 node integer NOT NULL,
 relations integer NOT NULL
);



INSERT INTO censored_nodes_one(node, relations)
VALUES
(2,25)
;



CREATE TABLE censored_nodes_two (
 node integer NOT NULL,
 relations integer NOT NULL
);



INSERT INTO censored_nodes_two(node, relations)
VALUES
(3,26)
;
```

In the code below, I took the node 1 as the first and want to bring only the nodes 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6.

```
with recursive search_graph("NODE", "DEPTH", "PATH") as (
    select
        1 AS NODE,
        0 AS DEPTH, 
        ARRAY[1] as PATH
    union 
        select
            be.TARGET_ID as NODE,
            sg."DEPTH" + 1 as DEPTH,
            sg."PATH" || be.TARGET_ID as PATH
        from
            bidirectional_edges as be
                inner join 
            search_graph as sg on
                sg."NODE" = be.SOURCE_ID
                left join
            censored_nodes_one as cno on
                sg."NODE" = cno.node
                left join
            censored_nodes_two as cnt on
                sg."NODE" = cnt.node
        where

                sg."DEPTH" < 2 and

                not (be.TARGET_ID) = any(sg."PATH") and

                (
                (be.FLAG_ONE = 1 and cno.node is null) OR
                (be.FLAG_TWO = 1 and cnt.node is null)
                 )

)
select *
from
    search_graph
```

Below, the query plan for this query:

```
CTE Scan on search_graph (cost=1705.74..1707.36 rows=81 width=40) (actual time=0.066..1.231 rows=6 loops=1)
 CTE search_graph
 -> Recursive Union (cost=0.00..1705.74 rows=81 width=40) (actual time=0.055..1.206 rows=6 loops=1)
 -> Result (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.030..0.031 rows=1 loops=1)
 -> Hash Left Join (cost=102.95..170.41 rows=8 width=40) (actual time=0.226..0.370 rows=2 loops=3)
 Hash Cond: (sg."NODE" = cnt.node)
 Filter: (((be.flag_one = 1) AND (cno.node IS NULL)) OR ((be.flag_two = 1) AND (cnt.node IS NULL)))
 Rows Removed by Filter: 16
 -> Hash Join (cost=42.10..47.71 rows=136 width=56) (actual time=0.161..0.279 rows=18 loops=3)
 Hash Cond: (be.source_id = sg."NODE")
 Join Filter: (be.target_id <> ALL (sg."PATH"))
 -> Seq Scan on teste_bidirectional_edges be (cost=0.00..1.81 rows=41 width=16) (actual time=0.084..0.197 rows=54 loops=2)
 Filter: ((flag_one = 1) OR (flag_two = 1))
 -> Hash (cost=41.68..41.68 rows=34 width=44) (actual time=0.084..0.084 rows=1 loops=3)
 Buckets: 1024 Batches: 1 Memory Usage: 8kB
 -> Hash Right Join (cost=0.26..41.68 rows=34 width=44) (actual time=0.062..0.065 rows=1 loops=3)
 Hash Cond: (cno.node = sg."NODE")
 -> Seq Scan on teste_censored_nodes_one cno (cost=0.00..32.60 rows=2260 width=4) (actual time=0.029..0.034 rows=1 loops=2)
 -> Hash (cost=0.22..0.22 rows=3 width=40) (actual time=0.021..0.021 rows=1 loops=3)
 Buckets: 1024 Batches: 1 Memory Usage: 8kB
 -> WorkTable Scan on search_graph sg (cost=0.00..0.22 rows=3 width=40) (actual time=0.009..0.010 rows=1 loops=3)
 Rows Removed by Filter: 1
 -> Hash (cost=32.60..32.60 rows=2260 width=4) (actual time=0.074..0.074 rows=1 loops=1)
 Buckets: 4096 Batches: 1 Memory Usage: 33kB
 -> Seq Scan on teste_censored_nodes_two cnt (cost=0.00..32.60 rows=2260 width=4) (actual time=0.057..0.060 rows=1 loops=1)
Planning time: 1.924 ms
Execution time: 1.707 ms
```

The table I need to use has about 740.000.000 rows, so when I try to run this recursive query, it takes a long time.

Comment: You should post `CREATE TABLE` statements. I coldn't get your example to run.

Comment: Thank you, I corrected the code, now it should run

Comment: 1.7 **milli** seconds ( = 0.0017 seconds) doesn't really seem that long to me. How fast do you need that to be? Also: when adding the execution plan, please make sure you preserve the indention. It is a vital part for understanding the plan.

Comment: I would  replace the two`LEFT JOIN...WHERE...NULL` s by `NOT EXISTS(...)` constructs

Answer (score 0):

I cannot really provide a solution – I also tried something similar to what @wildplasser suggests, but couldn't get it to run.

However, I have a few ideas that I want to share; maybe they can help you to solve this problem:

1. It seems cumbersome to have to join (or refer to in a `NOT EXISTS` clause) two other tables in each iteration. If you can get rid of that, your query will be so much faster.

   Since everything is joined on `sg."NODE"` (do yourself a favor and use lower case identifiers), you could just add another boolean field to `bidirectional_edges` and set it to the result of the `OR` condition ahead of time.

   So first you run a query that joins with `censored_nodes_one` and `censored_nodes_two` and sets the boolean field accordingly, then you run a recursive query using only `bidirectional_edges`.
2. If that does not work for some reason, you could do something similar with a CTE:

   ```
   WITH dbe_flagged AS (
       perform the join and provide an "artificial" boolean flag
   ),
   RECURSIVE search_graph AS (
       now run your recursive query on "dbe_flagged"
   )
   SELECT * FROM search_graph;
   ```

   The large size of the CTE result may be a problem here.
3. Don't forget to use indexes – for example, your query looks like it might profit from an index on `bidirectional_edges(source_id)`.